# How to post images here

Tags: support

I have plants I'd like to identify. How do I post pictures here?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a step-by-step way to post pictures.

In your question, or answer, click on the icon on the top row that looks like a box with a mountain in it. It's to the right of the brackets.

A window will open that looks like this:

[image: What comes up after pressing on picture icon]

If you want to post a picture from your computer, double click on the big box. Either drag and drop or double click the picture you want. You'll see a preview of it in the box. If you don't like it, click cancel and choose a different one. If you're happy with it, click "Add picture" and it will pop right in.

If you want an image that's already online, or that you have a url for, click on the sentence that says "You can also provide a link from the web." That will open a box that looks like this:

[image: Box you see choosing "add a link from the web"]

In that box you can put in the url of where the picture is, then choose "Add picture."

There are other ways to post images, using HTML to control things like size ratios. The [markdown help page](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images) explains that.